# Auto-selecting an <option> via JQuery in a dynamically-loaded <select>

Tags: html, jquery, dynamic, html-select

Based on cool StackOverflow code, I successfully created a series of dynamically-loaded `<SELECT>` drop-downs.  However, when processing the form (e.g., if there's an error in the submitted information) I need to automatically select the appropriate `<OPTION>` in the dynamically loaded `<SELECT>` blocks.  I tried a solution that works with static `<SELECT>` blocks, but it didn't work on my dynamically-loaded block. (I'm hiding/showing `<SELECT>` blocks as they are needed.)  Here's the code:

```
<?php do things at the beginning of the page ?>
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#container_A1').hide();
   $"#category_A0").change(function() {
      $("#category_A1").load("http://domain.com/loader/"+$("#category_A0").val());
      $("#container_A1").show();
   });
});
</script>

<?php create the HTML page... ?>

<script><?php

if( isset($_POST['category_A0']) && $_POST['category_A0'] != '' &&
    isset($_POST['category_A1']) && $_POST['category_A1'] != ''){  ?>

$(function() {
   $("#category_A1").load("http://domain.com/loader/"+$("#category_A0").val());
   $("#container_A1").show();
   $("#category_A1").val("<?php echo $_POST['category_A1']; ?>"); // NOT WORKING
});
<?php
}
?>
</script>
```

Everything works fine except the last JQuery line that tries to set the value of the category_A1 `<SELECT>` block to the option defined in $_POST['category_A1'].  That doesn't work.  Is the .load() function not complete when the subsequent .val() function is called?

Thanks!

Comment: You generally shouldn't mix server side and client side code.  It most likely won't work like you think (i.e. PHP has to finish everything it's doing before the JavaScript even starts).

Comment: I'm confused. Why am I seeing php code? The only php I might want to see would be that in `/domain.com/loader/`. Is that what's given above?

Comment: Brian Hoover's insight was perfect.  Most of the PHP code proved unecessary, but some is required ... like the $_POST data needed to build the JQuery scripts before they can be run.  Embedding the final .val() inside the .load() callback worked beautifully.  Regrettably, I'm forced to wait 8 hours before I can post a working example.

Answer (score 0):

.load is an asynchronous function. jQuery will continue on to the lines while .load is running, so the second `$("#category_A1").val("<?php echo $_POST['category_A1']; ?>");` will always be overriden by the result of `$("#category_A1").load("http://domain.com/loader/"+$("#category_A0").val());`

Comment: I suspected this would be the case.  How do I make the action synchronous?  Can I halt execution of the .val() function until the .load() function is complete?  Something akin to Javascript's OnLoad trigger?

Comment: There is a complete callback function in the .load specifications that will probably accomplish what you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/load/  You would set the value in the callback.